# Django Deploy issue

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm having a little trouble deploying a project. A program error is popping up when I try deploying my code.

Below is the exact message that I received. If anyone could help that would be great!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "OuterV_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...V_category"."name", "OuterV_category"."name" FROM "OuterV_ca...
```

````
Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "OuterV_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...V_category"."name", "OuterV_category"."name" FROM "OuterV_ca...
```                                                           ^
````

Comment: Looks like migrations were not run on your server, have you applied them?

Comment: remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "OuterV_category" does not exist
remote: LINE 1: ...V_category"."name", "OuterV_category"."name" FROM "OuterV_ca...
I've applied them but still being met with this error..

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your migrations when deploying your app to Heroku. You can either run migrate automatically during the release phase, or ssh into the server and run the migrate management command manually when needed.

To run migrations during the release phase, follow the example here -
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#specifying-release-phase-tasks

> To specify the tasks to run during the release phase, define a release process type in the app’s Procfile. For deploying Docker images to Heroku, learn more about using the release phase with Container Registry.
>
> In this Procfile example, release executes a Django database migration:
>
> ```
> release: python manage.py migrate
> web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
> ```
>
> Whereas in this example, release runs a script that includes several >different commands:
>
> ```
> release: ./release-tasks.sh
> web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
> ```

Comment: remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "OuterV_category" does not exist
remote: LINE 1: ...V_category"."name", "OuterV_category"."name" FROM "OuterV_ca...

Comment: I'm still given the same error even after making migrations. Can it be anything else?

Comment: Are your migration files up to date? Try running `python manage.py makemigrations` locally and see if there are any changes. If there are, commit them and try deploying again.

Comment: My Migrations are also up to date. not really sure what else to look at.